# Edit Contribution Form for receipt

Tags: contributions, contribution-page, receipts

How do I edit a contribution form to show the name of the organization and to put a note in like membership allows?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a custom fields for Contribution i.e by creating 
1. contact reference field that will list Organization.
2. Note field that will give you option to add notes.

Ref: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/

HTH
Pradeep